# mysql remove string with some pattern

Tags: mysql, replace

my question can be simply described as one line:

remove string with this pattern from one column in a table: **width="480" height="70"**

I have searched everywhere, no solution. Hope stackoverflow can help me finally.

Comment: Pls share what you have tried.

Comment: mysql does not support regex replacement.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE your_table
SET    your_column = REPLACE(your_column,'width="480" height="70"','')
```